# Facebook - Detect if user has liked your page?

Tags: php, facebook

Is there any way to detect if a user has liked X page outside of facebook?

So say my URL is:

```
http://www.site.com/page.html
```

My facebook page is:

```
http://www.facebook.com/myfacebookpage
```

Is there any way to detect if the user visiting my web page has liked my facebook page? and show text if they have or haven't liked it?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is if the user has authenticated with your application and has granted user_likes extended permission.  Then you could call /me/likes.